# Caesar Cipher program, How to use only characters a-z?

Tags: java, string, caesar-cipher

Caesar Cipher is applied individually to each letter in the string.  Each letter must be shifted forward n steps in the alphabet. If a letter is shifted off the end of the alphabet (‘z’), then it is shifted all the way back around to the beginning of the alphabet (‘a’). `

```
import java.util.*;

class question7{

    public static void main (String[] args ){

        String str = "";
        //allowing program to take user input using the keyboard
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 0;
        System.out.println("increasing the letters in string by n");

        while (true){
            System.out.println("Please enter your string");
            str = kb.nextLine(); 

            System.out.println("Please enter your n value");
            n = s.nextInt(); 

            String incrementedword=new String();
            for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
                incrementedword+=(char)(str.charAt(i)+n);
            }

            System.out.println ("your word is "+incrementedword);

        }
    }
}
```

for example, the following input (“hello world”,1) should return “ifmmp xpsme”

however when I type (“hello world”,1) the output is "ifmmp!xpsme"

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also "increment" the space character. Exclude it!

Comment: Also, your code won't work for 'z'.

Comment: I want 'z' to be 'a', but 'z' will be ' { ', i am a bit lost

Comment: Java won't automatically wrap back to 'a' if you add 1 to 'z', nor will it automatically exclude spaces and other non-letter characters.  You have to tell it to do these things.

Comment: You will need some `if`s: `if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) {....}`

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems here:

- You will get non-alphanumeric characters after you increment some characters close to the end of the alphabet (z+1 will become the curly brace **{**, for instance - see [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)). Try to use the remainder operator (%). For instance, 117 % 100 would be 17, 13 % 3 would be 1. This way (x + 1) % 10 would never go over 10, will start counting from 0 and up again as x increases.
- If you want only to encrypt characters in the a..z and A..Z range, exclude others. Simple comparison works: if (x>='a' && x <='z') .

I will not provide the complete and working code here because looks like a homework.

Comment: worth mentioning *why* those non-alphanumeric characters occur, for example by linking an ASCII / UNICODE table :>

Comment: Extended as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to control the wrap-around in case the letter is not in range. The wrap-around is to be done for letters that are shifted beyound the letter z. The code below will shift only letters in the string.

```
import java.util.*;

class question7{

public static void main (String[] args ){

    String str = "";
    //allowing program to take user input using the keyboard
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = 0;
    int a = 'a';
    int z = 'z';

    System.out.println("increasing the letters in string by n");

      while (true){
        System.out.println("Please enter your string");
        str = kb.nextLine().toLowerCase(); 

        System.out.println("Please enter your n value");
        n = s.nextInt(); 

        int newCharValue;
        int currentChar;

        String incrementedword=new String();
        for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

          currentChar = str.charAt(i);

          if(!Character.isLetter(currentChar)){
            incrementedword+=currentChar;
            continue;
          }

          newCharValue = currentChar + n;

          if(newCharValue <= z)
            incrementedword+=(char)newCharValue;
          else
            incrementedword+=(char)(a + (newCharValue - a + 1)%26);
        }
        System.out.println ("your word is "+incrementedword);
      }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps convert the letters into ascii, and then increment them that way?

I mean, that you'd have to set the constraints, 'a' being 97, and 'z' being 122. That would make sure it stays within lowercase characters, and you could tell it to loop back to 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Place a condition inside a loop that will check of the current character is from alphabet 'a' to 'z' lowercase:

Snippet code for checking if the current character is lowercase alphabet (a to z):

```
if (currentChar >= 'a' && currentChar <= 'z') {
//Process the shifting of the characters here
}
```

Now for shifting each letter forward n steps in the alphabet, try this formula:

```
if (currentChar >= 'a' && currentChar <= 'z') {
   currentChar = (char) ((currentChar - 'a' + k) % 26 + 'a');
//Where n is the number of shifts forward (ex: a + 2 = c)
}
```